# LVM_SETICONSPACING with virtual ListView in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, winforms-interop

I have an owner-drawn virtual listview. I set the view to LargeIcon, I set the LargeImageList to the appropriate image list, but when I call LVM_SETICONSPACING, it does not work! That is - it has no effect no matter what values I put in.

I use:

```
 Const LVM_FIRST As Long = &H1000
 Const LVM_SETICONSPACING As Long = LVM_FIRST + 53
 WinAPI.SendMessage(ListView.Handle, LVM_SETICONSPACING, 0, cy * 65536 + (cx And 65535))
```

I also tried:

```
 WinAPI.SendMessage(ListView.Handle, LVM_SETICONSPACING, 0, cy * 65536 + cx)
 WinAPI.SendMessage(ListView.Handle, LVM_SETICONSPACING, 0, cx * 65536 + cy)
```

All do absolutely nothing no matter what values for cx and cy I use. I tried from small like 10 to big like 400 for both - no difference.

I tried refreshing the list afterwards - no difference. item.bounds remains unchanged, and I have a 30px tall spacing between rows of icons. How do I get rid of that spacing?
I also tried variants with Ints and IntPtr-s for SendMessage.

Maybe the issue is that I use Windows 8 64 bit (though program is 32 bit)? Or the fact that in virtual mode, listview ignores this message?

I even checked that the message gets sent by trapping it in WndProc override.

Take 2:

I even tried with IntPtr as some have suggested w/o luck.
I also tried all possible values for the both vertical and horizontal spacing of 5:
&H50005000, &H00050005, as well as &H5000000050000000, &H0000000500000005. No difference, it is as if it is totally ignored. Maybe LVM_SETICONSPACING has a different value?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Your declaration for SendMessage() is wrong, the last 2 arguments are IntPtr.  Start there first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tied that, but it made no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit-wise shift with cx and cy in order to create the correct IntPtr works instead of using multiplication. This method is described in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101149/displaying-thumbnail-icons-128x128-pixels-or-larger-in-a-grid-in-listview).

```
Private Sub SetImageSpacingForListView(ByVal lView As ListView, ByVal cx As Short, ByVal cy As Short)
  ' http://qdevblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/c-listview-item-spacing.html
  ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761176(VS.85).aspx

  Dim LVM_FIRST As Integer = &H1000
  Dim LVM_SETICONSPACING As Integer = LVM_FIRST + 53
  WinAPI.SendMessage(lView.Handle, LVM_SETICONSPACING, IntPtr.Zero, CType(MakeLong(cx, cy), IntPtr))
End Sub

Private Function MakeLong(ByVal lowPart As Short, ByVal highPart As Short) As Integer
  Return CType(CType(lowPart, UShort) Or CType(highPart << 16, UInteger), Integer)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but it does not work on Windows 8.1 x64. Not sure about other OS-s. It does not seem to do anything at all no matter what values I use and whether I convert to IntPtr or not.