# Listview items vary in size depending on system?

Tags: c#, listview

I have a program that gathers some items and shows them as a list view, on my system it looks like this:

[image: My Computer]

And on another computer it looks like this:

[image: Other computer]

The relevant code for how I display items is as follows:

```
lvItems.View = View.LargeIcon;
lvItems.LargeImageList = imageList1;
```

And my imageSize is set to 64,64 for imageList1.

The tilesize property only affects the tile view and I tried that shortly but didn't like how it puts text on the right.

What would account for this difference between systems and how can I override it to get a consistent display?

Comment: Can you try to set `lvItems.LabelWrap = true;` and check the behavior on second pc?

Comment: @Ulugbek I just tried that and it did not work.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I also tried shortening the names themselves to be rather short and the spacing is still the same so it seems the problem has nothing to do with the text.

Comment: Can you check ListView_SetSpacing method in this question - [Displaying thumbnail icons 128x128 pixels or larger in a grid in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101149/displaying-thumbnail-icons-128x128-pixels-or-larger-in-a-grid-in-listview)?

Comment: That worked out great for me, for one of the listviews (I was using 3) it didn't work when applied beforehand but did when applied afterward, little strange but it's working fine in the end!