# C# ListView image icon size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The icons in the `ListView` in C# are very small by default (probably 16x16px). How can I increase the size of these icons?

I tried making the source images in the `ImageList` larger, and also tried using the `LargeImageList` property, but to no avail.

I'm using C#, WinForms and .net 4.0.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using WinForm? What .Net version?

Comment: Yes. WinForms and .net version 4.0

Comment: A great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101149/displaying-thumbnail-icons-128x128-pixels-or-larger-in-a-grid-in-listview?rq=1

Comment: You can set the ImageList.ImageSize to anything up to 256x256. Also look at the ColorDepth!! BTW: The height will determine the ListViewItemHeight

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The trick is in modifying the ImageSize propertiy of the ImageList (who would've thought)?

```
        listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;

        ImageList iList = new ImageList();
        iList.ImageSize = new Size(64, 64);  
        iList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

        listView1.LargeImageList = iList;
```

As a bonus, remember to set the View property of the ListView to be LargeIcon and also increase the ColorDepth (if you so desire).

Comment: _remember to set the View property of the ListView_ Well, that would depend on what he __wants__. Any mode will work!

Answer (score -1):

Use the `LargeImageList` property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.largeimagelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, but it still doesn't make the images bigger. You need to define a larger size image in the ImageList as well

Comment: @ShiroyChoksey - I didn't say it would  make the images bigger.   But you need to set that property if you want large images to show up.